# Why does adding more coils make my electromagnet weaker?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic

I've built a couple of simple electromagnets, using a nail (not sure of the material) and copper wire connected to a 1.5V AA battery. I'm really confused because the electromagnets with less coils are noticeably more powerful than the electromagnets with far more coils and I wanted to understand why. Could this be because of the added resistance of the coils? What can I change in my set-up to get higher magnetic field with increased coils?

Comment: Are you changing the dimensions of the coil when you add turns?  I.e., are you making it longer, or significantly fatter?  Are you using more turns of thinner wire, or adding turns of the same-sized wire?

Comment: Yes, resistance. The strength of an electromagnet is determined by current. But if you add more coils (either on top of each other or by making it longer) and keep the voltage the same, you get less current running through it. How many more coils did you add exactly?

Comment: 'less coils' should be 'fewer turns'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s increased resistance. Why? With a few simplifications, the principles are simple to understand.

- The generated magnetic field is proportional to the current through the coils and to the number of coils (per unit length). B ~ n*I
- The resistance of the electromagnet is proportional to the number of coils and to radius of the coils (technically to the length, but that’s just a 2pi constant). R ~ n*r
- Being at steady state, the current through the electromagnet is inversely proportional to the total resistance. I ~ 1/R

So, if all of the turns are the same radius (which would be physically impossible) you would have: B ~ n/(n*r) ~ 1/r regardless of the number of turns.

But as the radius of the turns increase as you add more layers of wire, in reality you have: B ~ n/(n1*r1+n2*r2+n3*r3...) where r1 < r2 < r3... and n=n1+n2+n3... Which decreases as you add more layers because of the increasing radius.

The optimum number of turns will be achieved when the increase in coil resistance  is exactly balanced by the increased voltage provided due to the reduction of load to the battery.

Comment: However, if we're up against a maximum heating-wattage, rather than a constant voltage, then adding a few more turns will let us crank up the volts a bit higher, in order to keep the wattage at maximum.  More amp-turns, same watts, so field-strength increases roughly as square root of total weight of copper wire, and turns-count only affects the required drive volts.